# Get Administrators of Google App Engine Project - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it possible to get the list of administrators in google app engine project programmatically in Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the billing administrator, as far as I know there is only one admin per app, anyway you cant access this info with the current API.

There is only the [appId API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/) that bring some info about the app but not the admin.